# boost::program_options conditionally required option

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

My executable has two modes of operation which are selectable via `--mode=foo` or `--mode=bar`. If mode=foo, then `--abc` option should be required and `--xyz` should not be specified. If mode=bar, then `--xyz` option should be required and `--abc` should not be specified. What is the correct way to code that?

Comment: I don't think there is any support for this, you'll have to validate it yourself after parsing the arguments